# Fill Array with HashMap<String, String>

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httprequest

**Updated:** I filled an array through HashMap, Iam using Asynctask for http request & after filling array put that array in dialog box. When I first run my app it gives me an empty dialog box & didn't give any error but when I re run my app it shows all array elements in dialog box perfectly. Whats the reason ?

```
//JsonResponse Inner Class in main class

private class JsonResponse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String response = "";
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> prServices_resultList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {   
            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
            {
            ResultList_List = prServices_resultList;    

            int z=0;

    for (HashMap<String, String> hashList : prServices_resultList)
             {
    Av_List[z] = hashList.get(android_Av_ID);

    Av_Lat[z]  = Double.parseDouble(hashList.get(android_Av_LAT));

    Av_Lng[z]  = Double.parseDouble(hashList.get(android_Av_LONG));

                z++;
            }  
            }
        }
        protected String doInBackground(final String... args)
        {    
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            JSONArray jArrayServices = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url_Services);

            try{
                for (int i = 0; i < jArrayServices.length(); i++) 
                {
            JSONObject jsonElements = jArrayServices.getJSONObject(i);

            String S_id = jsonElements.getString(android_S_ID);

            String S_name = jsonElements.getString(android_S_NAME);

        HashMap<String, String> hashServices = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key
                    hashServices.put(android_S_ID, S_id);
                    hashServices.put(android_S_NAME, S_name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    prServices_resultList.add(hashServices);
                }

                    response = "Success";
            }
                catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                return response;
        }
    }
```

In my main class when i press a button:

```
new JsonResponse().execute;
```

In main class above onCreate i declare like:

```
 static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ResultList_Services = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

String[] Db_Services  =  new String[ResultList_Services.size()];

    String[] Db_ServicesID  =  new String[ResultList_Services.size()];
```

Now I get an error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, adding values to static field `ResultList_Services` accessible for UI-thread from the background thread is very bad practice. You should rewrite your code to be thread-safe. The are several options, here is the one:

```
private class JsonResponse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ...

    protected String doInBackground(final String... args)
    {
        ...

        // adding HashList to private JsonResponse's field
        resultList.add(hashServices);

        ...
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {   
        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
        {
            ResultList_Services = resultList;
            //TODO: notify your Activity/Dialog on completion
        }
    }
}
```

Concerning your question - the reason for not seeing new records, is that you show the dialog when there are no values in the ResultList. You should request to show it from `onPostExecute`, for example.

Comment: if filling static from background thread is bad then what should i do.. Plz do tell me em very new to this

Comment: `ResultList_Services = resultList;` will handle this. Read carefully)

Comment: Yeah at first sight i missed it but then i got it what u try to explain me.. your help did make me to do a bit. if i got the desire result ill except your answer..

Comment: I did exactly as u advised now i get error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0..

Comment: At which line does this exception appear?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this -

```
for (HashMap<String, String> hashServices : ResultList_Services)
         {
            Db_Services[s] = hashServices.get(android_S_CName);

            Db_ServicesID[s] = hashServices.get(android_S_ID);
            s++;
        }
```

in **onPostExcecute()** block of your asynctask.